# how to remove leading zeros from negative numbers in shell

Tags: bash, sh

Is there any simple way to remove leading zeros from a negative number in shell? 
For example : for a number like -02, the output will be -2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a multiply ways to do this:

```
a="-02"
echo "$((a+0))"
```

Another with regex:

```
a="-02" 
echo "${a//-0/-}"
```

Or

```
a="-02" 
[[ "$a" =~ ^(-*|\+*)0*(.*)$ ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

And `bc`:

```
a="-02"
bc <<< "$a + 0"
```

Comment: I liked the option with bc. It also works with float, posive and negative numbers.  But in the case when a="+00" it does not work. Any way out ?

Comment: @GoutamDas In that case I think you would need to remove the `+`, something like this: `bc <<< "${a#+} + 0"`

Answer (score 1):

What about using the builtin `printf`?

```
$ num=-02
$ printf "%d\n" "$num"
-2
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution as I know is the following :

```
echo -02 | awk '{$0=int($0)}1'
```

but it only works with integer number. For floating is there any way?

Comment: dont cast it to int?